# type Null is not a subtype of type XiaomingLocalizations

Tags: flutter, dart

hello guys there is an error exception was thrown: type Null is not a subtype of type XiaomingLocalizations when I run the application in the mobile I confused what shall I do
it doesnt make errors in analyzer but when I open application in integral page red screen appear have this pharse exception was thrown type Null is not a subtype of type XiaomingLocalizations .

```
 import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class XiaomingLocalizations {
      final Locale? locale;
    
      XiaomingLocalizations(Locale? locale) : locale = locale;
    
     this is link of entire code
```

https://github.com/abdelrahman992-cpu/calcuu?fbclid=IwAR2utPXsXGaYB6lRRPXHBofezBPD4q-fEtOKEtDYEfwPEwfiepwtkeaCrM0